# How to pop up a message to inform the user?

Tags: ios, ios5, crash, ios6

I am reading data from server, however there is a certain time period (for example between 10 pm-6 am) there is no data. If user chooses within that certain time period, app is crashing! Is there any way to tell user there is no data, please choose other time period and prevent crashing!

Sorry if my question is so simple, but I could not able to come up with "key word" to search.

Any help or idea would be appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: check that the variable that stores the returned data is not nil before using it in your code.  if it is nil - no returned data, then avoid processing it.  that is likely the issue.

Comment: But however somehow I should let user know there is no data? Is it called notification? Like pop up small window inform user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you check that the data is nil, you can show a pop-up with a UIAlertView:

> ```
> UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
>                          initWithTitle:@"No New Data" 
>                          message:@"There is no new data to display. Please try again later." 
>                          delegate:nil
>                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
> [alert show];
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out why your app is crashing by looking at the stack trace of the crash.  If you can't understand it, edit your post and paste in the stack trace.

You can pop up a small window with a message using a [`UIAlertView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html).   You can easily find lots of examples by searching the web for “UIAlertView example”.